# Chrome CSS bug: image elements not showing up

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a CSS problem in Chrome (build: 17.0.9) with an image element that is not showing up. Please take a look at this link: http://next.lab501.ro/smartphone/nokia-n9-meego-to-go/3

In the top-right part of the main body you should see a list of pages with two image arrows acting as next and previous links. In Chrome only the next image arrow appears.

In any other browser (Firefox, IE9) everything shows up OK. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try fixing the typo in your doctype (PUBLLIC) and see if that clears anything up (<!DOCTYPE html PUBLLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "htpp://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict/dtd">
).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give .prev - float left [it will automatically make the element block].  is an inline element -> width, height, padding [top, bottom], margin[top, bottom] etc.. will not get applied unless its a block level element.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about float.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `float:left` in your .prev element, it shows up, but you have to lower the right padding so it gets closer to the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In http://next.lab501.ro/wp-content/themes/new-theme/style.css, it says:

```
.prev {
background: url(img/nav-left.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
padding: 3px 12px 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
width: 23px;
height: 22px;
}
```

Add a `float: left;` to the end of that. I would also change the padding on the right side to move it closer to the numbers. I changed it to 0 in this case. The code now looks like this:

```
.prev {
background: url(img/nav-left.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
padding: 3px 0 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
width: 23px;
height: 22px;
float: left;
}
```